# Boundedness of the input

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, control-theory, linear-control

$$
\dot x(t)=Ax(t)+Bu(t),\quad t\in[0,T]\\
x(0)=x_0\\
x(t)\text{ is bounded on }t\in[0,T]\\
A\text{ and }B\text{ are given constants},\quad B\neq 0
$$
My question:

> Is $u(t)$ also bounded on $t\in[0,T]$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I need to know more about how the problem was stated.  As stated u doesn't need to be bounded.  Why should it?  But as stated x-dot seems to be a function of variable u which I sort of doubt was the intent.

Comment: @fleablood Thanks for your attention. Now I update my question.

Comment: Even now, you should say something about $B$. If $B=0$, then $x$ will be bounded regardless of $u$.

Comment: @DelioM. Thanks for your comment. Yes, the condition $B\neq 0$ should be added.

Comment: This is not enough. Same holds if $B$ is a nonlinear operator with constant value, e.g., $Bz=1,000,000,000$ for all $z$. Is $B$, say, a bounded linear operator? On which space?

Comment: @DelioM. In my case, $A$ and $B$ are given constants.

Comment: I don't get it: are you saying that $A,B\in \mathbb R$?

Comment: @DelioM. Yes, this is a scalar problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, if $A,B\in \mathbb R$, then
$x(t)=x_0 e^{tA}+B(e^{\cdot A}*u)(t)$, where $*$ denotes the convolution of two functions. If you assume $u$ to be continuous, then the above function is continuous and hence it attains a maximum on the compact interval $[0,T]$, but even if this is not the case, for fixed $T$ the sought-after boundedness follows from Young's inequality for convolutions.

EDIT: Sorry, as correctly pointed out by @obaarey the non-continuous case is wrong. I was thinking of applying the vector-valued Young estimate $\|e^{\cdot A}*u\|_\infty\le \|e^{\cdot A}\|_\infty \|u\|_1$ (in fact, $e^{\cdot A}*u$ is even an absolutely continuous and hence uniformly continuous vector-valued function), which however goes in the "wrong" direction and shows that an unbounded solution implies an unbounded control.

Comment: Out of curiosity, let $A=0$, then $x(t) = \int_0^t u(\tau) d \tau$. Can't we find a non-continuous $u(t)$ in $[0, T]$ which is unbounded but its integral is bounded?

Comment: Yes, the non-continuous case is problematic.

Comment: @obaarey Your formula is wrong - it should read $x(t)=x_0+B\int_0^t u(\tau)d\tau$. And the answer to your question is: yes, of course: simply take a monotonically increasing sequence $(\tau_n)\subset (0,T)$ converging to $T$ and let $u(\tau_n):=n$ and $u(\tau)\equiv 0$ in all other points. Then of course $\int_0^T u(\tau)d\tau=0$.

Comment: @DelioM. Then boundedness of $x(t)$ doesn't imply boundedness of $u(t)$ if $u(t)$ is not continuous. But in your answer "but even if this [continuity] is not the case, for fixed $T$ the sought-after boundedness follows from Young's inequality for convolutions."

Comment: @obaarey. Thanks, you're right, I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Let $x(0)=0$ and $x(t)=t^2\cos (t^{-2})$ for $t\ne 0$.The function $x(t)$ is differentiable at every $t$ but $x'(t)$ is unbounded on $[0,T]$ for any $T>0 $ . (Consider $t=1/\sqrt {2\pi n}$ for $n\in N.$) Note that $x'(t)$ is not continuous at $t=0$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your answer. Are you taking B=0B=0? But then the above equation becomes a linear homogeneous ODE, which are necessarily solved by exponential functions. Where do you get a solution of your kind from?

Comment: @DelioM. I think he considers the case $A=0$, not $B=0$.

Comment: @user143763 Ah, I see. You're of course right, and so is he.

Comment: If x'-Ax=Bu with constant A and constant B$\ne 0$ , if x is bounded but x' is not, then u is unbounded.